# Link in document is wrong in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

My umbraco is running with uBootstrap starter kit.

The home node's link to document is showing http://en.umbraco.local/. where does this value come from?
How can I change it to my domain name? Thanks.
[image: Admin panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the home node and hit "culture and hostnames" you can add a different domain in there.